# react-images why does the lightbox show by default and lose its styling as an import

Tags: reactjs

I am working off [this Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-photo-gallery-with-lightbox-tdv66) as my starting point. Here you can see that by default the lightbox is hidden and then when you click the button it opens the lightbox which is in a fixed position above the rest of the content with a background color with transparency. However, when I try to set this up as an import in another component, the lightbox is visible by default, it also loses it's styling and I am not seeing a close button. Any ideas why this is happening?

```
import React from "react";
import LB from "./LB";
import "./styles.css";

const photos = [
  {
    src: "https://source.unsplash.com/2ShvY8Lf6l0/800x599",
    width: 4,
    height: 3
  },
  {
    src: "https://source.unsplash.com/Dm-qxdynoEc/800x799",
    width: 1,
    height: 1
  },
  {
    src: "https://source.unsplash.com/qDkso9nvCg0/600x799",
    width: 3,
    height: 4
  },
  {
    src: "https://source.unsplash.com/iecJiKe_RNg/600x799",
    width: 3,
    height: 4
  },
  {
    src: "https://source.unsplash.com/epcsn8Ed8kY/600x799",
    width: 3,
    height: 4
  },
  {
    src: "https://source.unsplash.com/NQSWvyVRIJk/800x599",
    width: 4,
    height: 3
  },
  {
    src: "https://source.unsplash.com/zh7GEuORbUw/600x799",
    width: 3,
    height: 4
  },
  {
    src: "https://source.unsplash.com/PpOHJezOalU/800x599",
    width: 4,
    height: 3
  },
  {
    src: "https://source.unsplash.com/I1ASdgphUH4/800x599",
    width: 4,
    height: 3
  }
];

export default function App() {
  return <LB images={photos} />;
}
```

[Here's my updated codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-moon-5bt16) with what I've tried so far(also where you can see the lightbox being shown by default without styling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [code sandbox project](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-photo-gallery-with-lightbox-tdv66) that you've taken the example code is using [`react-images@0.5.13`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-images/v/0.5.13) and at your [updated code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-ramanujan-cbi9c) you're using [`react-image@1.1.0-beta.3`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-images/v/1.1.0-beta.3).

Version `1.1.0-beta.3` does not work as the old `0.5.13` as it has no prop `isOpen`. You either downgrade to [`react-images@0.5.13`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-images/v/0.5.13), or check the [Using the Modal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-images/v/1.1.0-beta.3#using-the-modal) example at [`react-image@1.1.0-beta.3`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-images/v/1.1.0-beta.3) page.

I suggest you consider upgrading to [`react-image@1.1.0-beta.3`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-images/v/1.1.0-beta.3), because if you check the console at the example [code sandbox project](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-photo-gallery-with-lightbox-tdv66), you'll see a bunch of deprecation errors.

Here is a [Stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-images-modal?file=index.js) with your example modal converted to latest version [`react-image@1.1.0-beta.3`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-images/v/1.1.0-beta.3) if you want to switch.

Comment: Welp, I feel stupid now haha! I will award the bounty tomorrow. Thank you!

Comment: Don't feel stupid, It can happen to all of us. I have faced such issues and spend hours and hours just to find out I have had wrong or old versions installed. Don't worry about the bounty, it gets automatically rewarded to the accepted answer when it expires.

Answer (score 1):

I tock a look to your code here [enter link description here](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-moon-5bt16) then I search about the package react-image, its nice package and I like it actually, then I compare your code with the docs [react-images in npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-images) , I think you dont need to add the events to the Lightbox as thire code :

```
   return (
      <ModalGateway>
        {modalIsOpen ? (
          <Modal onClose={this.toggleModal}>
            <Carousel views={images} />
          </Modal>
        ) : null}
      </ModalGateway>
    );
```

just you need to give the module onClose function and the Carousel the array of images

actually I rewrote the code using ES6 "to be honest I like arrow function more than binding things " just inside the LB component file i added

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Carousel, { Modal, ModalGateway } from "react-images";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    currentImage: 0,
    modalIsOpen: false
  };
  openLightbox = () => {
    this.setState({
      currentImage: 0,
      modalIsOpen: true
    });
  };
  closeLightbox = () => {
    this.setState({
      currentImage: 0,
      modalIsOpen: false
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <button onClick={this.openLightbox}>Open Lightbox</button>

        <ModalGateway>
          {this.state.modalIsOpen ? (
            <Modal onClose={this.closeLightbox}>
              <Carousel views={this.props.images} />
            </Modal>
          ) : null}
        </ModalGateway>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you, but [the example I am working off](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-photo-gallery-with-lightbox-tdv66) of does not use those additional components from `react-images` and the lightbox still functions the way I would expect it to